# How can i fix it ? : TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

My code ;

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "985545865856958504");
message.author.roles.add(role)
```

İ using this code in eval command and i taking this error. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Try `console.log()` role and and message.author then share results, because this error comes if  the role your adding is undefined

Comment: yes , now i used message.mentions.members.first() || message.member
and worked

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`Message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=author), which is giving you a user, but not a member, and you cannot give a role to users! To get a member you should use [`Message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=member) instead!

Comment: I'm trying to give myself the role

Comment: let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "985516537622446140");
let drake = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member
drake.roles.add(role);

now i used it and working